# Understanding second argument in the function "xdrmem_create"

Tags: c, udp, ganglia, xdr

I was debugging [ganglia](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/) and came through sending data using XDR through UDP channel.
I found the second argument of the function `xdrmem_create ( xdrs, addr, size, op)` strange.
Where the syntax of the arguments are given as:

```
XDR *xdrs;
char *addr;
u_int size;
enum xdr_op op;
```

The reference of this function is [here](http://ps-2.kev009.com/wisclibrary/aix51/usr/share/man/info/en_US/a_doc_lib/libs/commtrf1/xdrmem_create.htm).

As you can see, the second argument (xdrs) of this function is a character array. And this is similarly declared in one of the ganglia's function as `char msgbuf[GANGLIA_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];`.

After calling above function as `xdrmem_create(&x, msgbuf, GANGLIA_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN, XDR_ENCODE);` in ganglia , appropriate data in the ganglia's specific structure (`cb->msg`) is encoded to XDR format by calling the function `xdr_Ganglia_value_msg(&x, &(cb->msg))` where `x` is an `XDR` type of variable.

Later, to send the encoded data through UDP channel, the function `Ganglia_udp_send_message( udp_send_channels, msgbuf, len);` is called.
To understand how this XDR data is sent, I tried to print the output of the content of `msgbuf` using `fprintf` but it always print nothing in spite of the fact that it is a character array . And it is also evident that the encoded data is sent successfully.

So, my question is, How data encoded into XDR format is being sent through UDP channel here?

I have pasted a part of code from ganglia [here](http://paste.bradleygill.com/index.php?paste_id=178644). You can see from the line 131 to 136 for your reference.

Comment: Does this character array contain 0-bytes?

Comment: I had tried to print the length of `msgbuf` using `strlen()` and it always returned zero. while `sizeof()` returns 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages are encoded with XDR, a binary format. The XDR libraries used are old, and a modern version of the API probably would have used uint8_t instead of char. Despite it using char, it is binary data - i.e. you cannot print the data as a string.

If you want to print this data, use a loop where you print each byte as hex e.g. by doing `printf("%02X ", msgbuf[i]);`

Read [RFC4506](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4506.txt) to learn about the XDR encoding. The actual messages are described in an XDR language specification, and run through a code generation tool (e.g. [rpcgen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rpcgen) for C code) to generate code for encoding/decoding. See https://github.com/fastly/ganglia/blob/master/lib/gm_protocol.x for the message definitions that Ganglia defines.